# Declaring Text Decorations such as Underline, Strikethrough in a Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, text, styles

How do I include text decorations such as Underline, Strikethrough etc in a Style definition:

```
<Style x:Key="UnderlinedLabel">
     <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS" />
     <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="14" />
     <!-- Next line fails -->
     <Setter Property="Control.TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
</Style>
```

I'm familiar with using the following XAML to underline text:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Underline>
       Underlined text
   </Underline>
</TextBlock>
```

However text decoration is just another style, I want to be able to define it declaritively like FontWeight, FontSize etc.

[Update]

I was applying this style to a Label control.  This was my main problem.  It appears you can't underline text in a Label.  Change to a TextBlock (thanks gix) and all is well.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Underlining text can be done either with `<Underline>...</Underline>` or with the `TextDecorations` attribute set to `Underline`. You can include the latter in a style definition:

```
<Style x:Key="Underlined">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
</Style>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Underlined}">
    Foo
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: +1 - I think it's just the fact that @Ash is using "Control.TextDecorations" rather than "TextBlock.TextDecorations".

Comment: @Matt, half right, I was also applying that Style to a Label control, no underlining was displayed.  When I changed to a TextBlock it is displayed???

Comment: Hi how to apply StrikeThrough to text of a textblock??? is there any property for that in Silverlight 4.0?

Comment: Same as Underline...
`<TextBlock Text="Some Text" TextDecorations="Strikethrough" />`